# Закрытие блока, при клике вне него

Tags: javascript, jquery

У меня есть блок, допустим `<div class="wallets-deposit__inner" id="DEP">`он вложенный. Как сделать так, чтобы при клике вне него, меня переносило на определенную страницу?

Answer (score 1):

Попробуй так.

```
   $(document).mouseup(function (e) {
        var container = $('#DEP');
        if (container.has(e.target).length === 0){
            $(location).attr('href',url);
        }
    });
```

А вообще, в гугле полно ответов)

Answer (score 1):

Вот пара вариантов

```
var url = "https://";
// Ссылка на объект div в модели dom
var dep = document.getElementById("DEP");
// Регистрируем обработчик события клика, общего уровня
dep.addEventListener("click", function(event) {
  // Вариант #1/ Перенаправить по адресу
  location.href = url;

  // Вариант #2/ Открыть новую вкладку с указанным адресом
  window.open(url, "_blank");
}, false);
```